# How to change the appearance of an android view with a click listener and background worker?

Tags: android

I have an android app that users can use to check into a course at a certain time. Their daily schedule shows up on a RecyclerView as a series of CardViews. Each CardView has basic information about each class, including instructor name, course title, attendance status, etc..
 The app communicates with a MySQL database through a php script which is called from an AsyncTask background worker. In the PostExecute method, the app receives a result from the php script ("Present" if checking in on time, "Tardy" if late, "Absent" if totally missed) to show in an AlertDialog. The PostExecute method also sets a String variable to equal the result.

```
The background worker is called from a click listener like so:

baf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int bright = status.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPresent);
                    status.setBackgroundColor(bright);

                    lol = getAdapterPosition()+1;
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String time = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                    Log.d("Current Time",time);
                    String type="checkin";
                    PresentBackgroundWorker presentBackgroundWorker = new PresentBackgroundWorker(getActivity());
                    presentBackgroundWorker.execute(type,date,time, "t"+String.valueOf(lol));
                    String aaa = ontime;
                    status.setText(aaa);

                }
            });
```

The variable ontime (global variable) is the result from the php script, and its value is set from the background worker like so:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        writeitout(result);

        alertDialog.setMessage(result);


        alertDialog.show();
    }

private void writeitout(String string) {
    ontime = string;
    Log.d("STATS",ontime);
}
```

Based on the `Log.d()` commands, the ontime variable is changing appropriately, but the change to the 'status' TextView is delayed by one click. That is, the result for the previous course, shows up for the present course. How do I make sure the changes in the ontime variable show up on time?

**EDIT: ADDED ORIGINAL COURSEADAPTER**

```
public class CourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Course> courseList;


    public CourseAdapter(List<Course> sc) { this.courseList = sc; }

    public class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, teacher, type, status;
        FloatingActionButton baf;
        View subIten;
        int lol;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);
            teacher = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textteach);
            type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.texttype);
            baf = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            status = view.findViewById(R.id.textstatus);
            subIten = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_item);
        }
        private void bind(Course course) {
            title.setText(course.getTitle());
            teacher.setText(course.getTeacher());
            type.setText(course.getType());
            baf.setImageResource(course.getPhotoID());
            baf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int bright = status.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPresent);
                    status.setBackgroundColor(bright);

                    lol = getAdapterPosition()+1;
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String time = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                    Log.d("Current Time",time);
                    String type="checkin";
                    PresentBackgroundWorker presentBackgroundWorker = new PresentBackgroundWorker(getActivity());
                    presentBackgroundWorker.execute(type,date,time, "t"+String.valueOf(lol));

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CourseAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CourseAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Course course = courseList.get(position);
        holder.bind(course);

    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return courseList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do much Java but where does `status` come from. Is that in scope in the onClick function?

Comment: `status` is the TextView within the CardView that shows attendance status

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. I don't see `status` instantiated or passed into the function. For example does this work? `Log.d(status.getText());`, assuming it has some default text value.

Comment: `baf.setOnClickListener()` is called inside a `RecyclerView.Viewholder` class where `status` is instantiated and its default value is "Absent", so the `log` command you suggested does work

Comment: Well that was my only guess. Is there some way to call a view "refresh" or something? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are saving the asynctask result in a variable and then later accessing it on button click.
So, what basically is happening here:

1. You click on a button
2. you start asynctask
3. your asynctask is still working. So, onTime still has no string. And, status.setText() is being called even before the asynctask produce result and save it in onTime.
4. your asynctask has finished it's job and saved the result in onTime, but the button has already finished it's rest of the code, so textview doesn't get the latest change.
5. you again click on the button
6. your asynctask again starts to work, but this time onTime has a value because previous asynctask saved it's result in it. so when status.setText() is being called, it set's the value of onTime (which holds the result from previous asynctask)

So, to fix the issue, **you shouldn't update the textview on button click**, rather update them inside asynctask's onPostExecute()

**Just change your onPostExecute() like this** and you have your solution.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  writeitout(result);
  status.setText(result); //updating the textview directly here
  alertDialog.setMessage(result);
  alertDialog.show();
}
```

**Also, remove this two lines from your baf clickListener**

```
String aaa = ontime;
status.setText(aaa);
```

Comment: Your approach does change the text in the status TextView right on PostExecute, but weirdly its changing the status for the final course in the CardView not matter which button I press

Comment: Would you like to explain a little bit more? I hope I can help you @InigoMontoyaJr

Comment: Yes @ash12. In my previous setup I set the click listener for each of the buttons in a RecyclerView Adapter. Level-wise the Adapter goes: public class CourseAdapter -> public class ViewHolder (define and set the TextView for each card element)-> private void bind ->baf,setOnClickListener -> calling the BackgroundWorker. The public class for the Background Worker is on the same level as the public class Adapter.

Comment: To make your solution work, I defined the TextView status as a global variable while still setting it inside the Adapter. When I call the Background Worker, the text meant for the status TextView shows up in the last entry instead of the corresponding entry

Comment: Can you add adapter class in your question?
The problem is happening because of the textview status setting as a global variable. But to give you a solid answer, I need to look at the adapter class thoroughly and update my answer accordingly so that anyone searching for this problem gets help

Comment: I moved the `public class BackgroundWorker` inside the ViewHolder level of the `public class CourseAdapter` and it worked! I hope I'm not violating too many coding practices